# SSDT AUTOMATICALLY GETTING RELAUCHED

Tags: reporting-services

I was using SSDT for reporting services. I connected to database engine. I created data source using a local server with windows authentication. While creating a dataset, it is showing error `'unable to connect to data source'`. Somehow it was able to connect, but while viewing report preview the tool is getting close and reopening again by itself.

Can anyone please let me know where might be the mistake?

Comment: Sounds like Visual Studio is crashing. When Visual Studio crashes it will attempt to launch again and reopen your project. Something in you project is causing it to crash when you preview the report. Hard to say exactly what with the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you ....I will try reinstalling software